# Converting a $xA + yI = A^2$ to a different form

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms

$xA + yI = A^2$ is an equation where $x$ and $y$ are both scalars, not vectors.

I can solve this (assuming the solution exists) by simply pulling out a series of scalar equations. An example of the matrix $A$ would be:

```
[1,1,0]
[0,1,0]
[0,0,1]
```

From this, matrix we see that there are exactly two unique equations to solve: $x+y = -1$ and $x +0 y = -2$.

This is a pretty easy example to do on paper.

What I am trying to achieve is an algorithm that takes the equation in the form specified and converts it to a matrix eqation of the form $A\vec x = \vec v$, where $v$ will contain elements $x,y$. The reason for this is that I am using a software library that can solve the equation in the latter form, but not the former.

Is there an algorithmic way to do this?

**EDIT: I found the following algorithm on stackoverflow, but need an explanation of how it works:**

1. Flatten the matrices $A$ and $I$ into column vectors $a$ and $i$ in
   row-major order.
2. Let the matrix $B$ be defined as the matrix whose columns are the
   flattened versions of $a$ and $i$.
3. let the vector $c$ be the column vector made by flattening $A^2$.
4. Then, solving the equation $Bz = -c$ will give a solution, when
   using numpy's least squares solver.

What I don't understand is how this is possible, because $B$ and $z$ are not the correct dimensions to support matrix multiplication.

**Can anyone explain this to me?**

Comment: Just “flatten” the three matrices.

Comment: Ok, I know how to do that with numpy. Let me try to work it out.

Comment: @amd I flattened my matrices, but that does not solve the problem. They are still incompatible with the numpy library's linear algebra solver, which takes 2 arguments: a coefficient matrix and a solution vector. I need a way to parse the linear equations from the matrix equation.

Comment: @amd If I take $B$ to be the matrix comprised of columns of the flattened matrices $A$ and $I$ and use $c$ as the column vector formed by flattening $A^2$, I found that numpy's least squares function finds the correct solution. Is there a purer way to do this, using only linear algebra?

Comment: There you go. That’s as “pure” as it gets.

Comment: Ok, cool! If you'd like to expand all of that into an answer, I'd be happy to accept it. Otherwise I'll answer it myself in a couple days :)